# How do I remove a query string from a URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, hosting

The text editor (Tiny MCE) on my Wordpress site is not working. I am using a fresh install of Wordpress and the default twenty-sixteen theme. I do not have any plugins installed.

Looking at the dev tools I can see this error:

`tinymce.min.js?ver=4800-20180716:formatted:4787 GET http://website.com/new/wp-includes/js/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.min.js?wp-mce-4800-20180716 400 (Bad Request)`

The server is not resolving the URL due to the query string at the end.

If I open this URL in a new tab and remove the `?wp-mce-4800-20180716` then it will resolve the file.

I understand that this may be a problem with my host environment so I am trying to create a new rule in my htaccess file to strip the `?wp-mce-xxxxxx` from the URL like this:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)\?wp-mce-.*$ $1 [L]`

But I am not having much luck.

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think your RewriteRule won't detect the QUERY_STRING

you should use

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} wp-mce
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L,QSD]
```

Comment: This won't work, your syntax is wrong. It should be `%{QUERY_STRING}` not `{%QUERY_STRING%}`.... fix that.

Comment: Your edit was still a little wrong, so I've corrected that for you :)

Comment: I am getting a 500 server error with this due to the QSD flag. Is there a solution for an older Apache version?

Comment: not sure , but i think you can try RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?foo [L] : it may overwrite the query string